# How do I convert a Unix timestamp string to time_t in C++11?

Tags: c++, unix, c++11, time-t, feedly

### Short question, aka "TD;DR".

I have a, say, "1464478647000" string, that I guess is a UNIX timestamp. But surely it is a string containing a number that represents time, but **not in a human readable format**. How do I convert it to a `time_t` type so I can format it later to a formated string, like "3 minutes ago" in C++11?

---

### Long question.

Sorry for my bad english, first of all.

I'm totally noob at C++11, and even C++; I just learnt a little of C and that was like 10 years ago, I almost forgot how it was. On my spare time, I'm trying to do a little fork of [Feednix](https://github.com/JarkoreDrake/Feednix) (a ncurses program, written in C++11, that acts as a Feedly client for Linux console - and looks like it's dead) so it looks more like a list (kind of how [ncmpcpp](http://rybczak.net/ncmpcpp/) or [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) look like). As the current [Feednix](https://github.com/JarkoreDrake/Feednix) implementation is not showing time of any post, I thought it would be nice to make it show the time it was published (as the web version of Feedly does, on its "Titles only" presentation).

The thing is that following the model of what's implemented on [Feednix](https://github.com/JarkoreDrake/Feednix), I'm pulling the 'published' data as a string object (I couldn't figure how to pull it as an integer, or directly as a `time_t` object (seems the Json library doesn't allow to do that). Said 'published' data, says Feedly API docs, is "the timestamp, in ms, when this article was published, as reported by the RSS feed (often inaccurate)." An example of that is "1452614967000".

So how can I do to convert that string to a `time_t` object, so I can later format it to a string like "3 minutes ago" or "2 days ago"? Or is anything better I can do to get that formatted string (which is more likely)? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1452614967000 cannot be a `time_t` timestamp. Otherwise it would be `July 15, 48001, 01:30:00 -0400`

Comment: @Sam, it's *probably* milliseconds since, if you lop the "000" of the end, you get sometime Jan 12 this year, as opposed to sometime long after the human race may well have become extinct :-)

Comment: What does "TD;DR" mean? Whatever happened to simple words like "summary"?

Comment: Too ... dopey? damn long? drab? ... didn't read? :-)

Comment: Actually, just noticed the question *states* it's in milliseconds so my comment is superfluous. I'll leave it there as a monument to my inability to read before spewing forth rubbish :-)

Answer (score 3):

First, convert the number into `long` using `strtol`, then cast to `time_t`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std; // to simplify answer

...
const char* timestr = "1464478647000";
time_t timenum = (time_t) strtol(timestr, NULL, 10);
```

Comment: You appear to be missing the step "convert to '3 minutes ago'" :-) Though, granted, you *did* say "First, ...". Also, would you need `ctime` as well?

Comment: It is not guaranteed that `time_t` is of `long` type. On some architectures it may be 32 bit integer and your cast will cause an owerflow.

Comment: I think you need to use mktime() ... see "duplicate of"